# Is running unittest tests for Python under Visual Studio always this slow?

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015

I have a small Python project, just a few files and a few test files. There are 32 tests. I have been using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 to write the code, and it works great for running the code, editing, and so on. It even found all the unit tests, and when I run them, it'll put green and red marks next to them depending on whether they pass or fail.

However, when I choose "Run All" in Visual Studio (that is, run the tests without debugging), it takes 19 seconds to run the 32 tests, and they're all taking about 300-400ms each to run. At first, I just thought, well, I guess running unit tests is just slower in Python.

But if I drop out to a command line, and do:

```
Python -m unittest test1.py test2.py test3.py [etc]
```

Then it runs the 32 tests successfully in 13ms. So, it's over 1000 times faster.

I can't seem to find any options or settings anywhere in Visual Studio that would allow me to change anything about testing. I can understand it taking a little longer because it records each test individually and marks the pass/fail state next to the item in the test explorer. But 1000 times slower? Nope.

At the moment, 19s isn't too long to wait. But when this hits 100 or 1000 tests, I'm going to be looking at large numbers of minutes to run the unit tests. Or just dropping out to the command line and not having nicely collected information about any tests that might have failed.

Has anyone else had this problem, or can anyone imagine what might be causing it? Or am I just stuck with it?

Comment: Worst case, just run from command line. :)

Comment: Well yes, I had thought of that and have made myself a script to find all the tests and run them.

Comment: all graphic api are slow, you get the benefit of tooltips, autocompletiion, plugins, all possible libs loaded, it is one of the reasons that command line tools never dies

Comment: It's not doing any graphics. I'm talking about the actual time taken to run the test, not the time taken to update the UI afterwards or anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that this is because it runs every test separately (i.e. it's as if you did `python -m unittest test1.py; python -m unittest test2.py; ...`).

Comment: Nope. If I run a single file with 4 tests in it, running it from Visual Studio takes a total of 3s, with times for the individual tests between 390 and 760 milliseconds.If I run that same file from the command line, all four tests are complete in a total of 3 milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: it runs a separate process for _every test_, rather than every file with tests.

Comment: Ouch. I can see why: so it can get the result. However, given that it takes such a short time, it would be nice if it would run them all first. If they all pass, no need to go through and run them individually, looking for which ones failed.

Comment: Yes, and it could get the results more efficiently, too (basically having some custom entry point that would run the tests, collect the results, and then send them over to VS for parsing). The current approach is the easiest one by far, though, and was all that would fit in schedule when the feature was originally added.

Comment: It seems that there's no work item to improve this currently, so feel free to file it at https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues

Comment: Thanks Pavel! I've logged that request.